# How to bind a ListBox to the Return Key in order to close the window

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, pycharm

This seems like a fairly straightforward problem but I cannot get to solve it. When the following code is run, the first window comes with two entry boxes. When we use 'TAB' key, the second entry box will pop out a window from which a value needs to be selected from a ListBox. I have coded the part where the value in the ListBox needs to come into the entry box of the first window, however, I am unable to get the second window to close once the selection is made.

```
from Tkinter import *

def fn_jump(event=None):



    def listbox_update(data):
        # delete previous data
        listbox.delete(0, 'end')

        # put new data
        for item in data:
            listbox.insert('end', item)

    def on_select(event):
        # display element selected on list
        print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
        print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
        a = (event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
        print a
        txtbox2.delete(0, END)
        txtbox2.insert(0,a)
        #listbox.bind('<<Return>>', window3.quit())   #This is not working



    window3 = Toplevel()
    window3.title("This window popped out")
    window3.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500,200))



    listbox = Listbox(window3, width=60)
    listbox.grid(row=0)

    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)


    test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry')

    listbox_update(test_list)


root = Tk()
txtbox1 = Entry(root)
txtbox2 = Entry(root)

txtbox1.grid(row=0)
txtbox2.grid(row=1)

txtbox2.bind('<KeyRelease>', fn_jump)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario, since the functions are defined within a function, just destroying the window means that the program is still within the parent function fn_jump thereby popping out the second window over and over again.
In order to overcome this, I have forcefully set the focus to a textbox on the root window which solves the problem (I would think that there would be an exit() which we could use, but I am relatively new to Python).

This is the final working code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def fn_jump(event=None):

    def listbox_update(data):
        # delete previous data
        listbox.delete(0, 'end')

        # put new data
        for item in data:
            listbox.insert('end', item)

    def on_select(event):
        # display element selected on list
        print('(event) previous:', event.widget.get('active'))
        print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
        a = (event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))
        print a
        txtbox2.delete(0, END)
        txtbox2.insert(0,a)


    window3 = Toplevel()
    window3.title("This window popped out")
    window3.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500,200))
    listbox = Listbox(window3, width=60)
    listbox.grid(row=0)
    listbox.focus_set()
    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
    listbox.bind('<Return>', lambda event: window3.destroy())  #This is a fix
    txtbox1.focus_set()                                        #This is a fix
    test_list = ('apple', 'banana', 'Cranberry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise', 'Strawberry')
    listbox_update(test_list)


root = Tk()
txtbox1 = Entry(root)
txtbox2 = Entry(root)

txtbox1.grid(row=0)
txtbox2.grid(row=1)

txtbox2.bind('<KeyRelease>', fn_jump)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
#listbox.bind('<<Return>>', window3.quit())   #This is not working
```

with:

```
listbox.bind('<Return>', lambda event : window3.destroy())
```

As you can see with `txtbox2.bind('<KeyRelease>', fn_jump)` `bind` expects a *reference* to the callback function to be used. Also correct bindtype for pressing enter is `'<Return>'` not `'<<Return>>'`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your comment pointed me in the right direction but did not fulfill the requirement. I will post an answer myself.

Comment: @mdabdullah I was unaware of the requirement that the window shouldn't repop up. That's because releasing enter key _is_ still a key release that calls `fn_jump` due to `txtbox2.bind('<KeyRelease>', fn_jump)`. That's not included in the question though.